# Node/Express Cannot POST error (React frontend)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post

For my React/Express app, I've already built my backend API in Express, including a route for posting a blog post (/api/posts). On the front end, I built a form with a method of POST that submits to this route, but when I submit the form I get the error "Cannot POST /api/posts".

**app.js (Express)**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

//Load routes
const photos = require('./routes/photos');
const posts = require('./routes/posts');
const recs = require('./routes/recs');

// DB config
const db = require('./config/database');

//Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

// Body parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session Middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  //cookie: {secure: true}

}));

//Router
app.use('/api/photos', photos);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);
app.use('/api/posts', recs);


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Post Route**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Load Posts model
require('../models/Post');
const Post = mongoose.model('posts')

// Get all posts
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .sort({date:'desc'})
    .then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err);
    })
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); //testing info I receive for now
})
```

Form

```
const postForm =
    <div className="form-popup" id="newPost">
      <form action="/api/posts" method="post" className="form-container">
        <h1>New Blog Post</h1>

        <label htmlFor="title"><b>Title</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Blog Post Title" name="title" required />

        <label htmlFor="location"><b>Location</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" required />

        <textarea placeholder="Your post here" name="content" required />

        <button type="submit" className="btn">Post</button>
        <button type="submit" className="btn cancel" onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you able to access the API via postman?

Comment: @DanPhilip Nope, I'm getting the same error there. I'm not sure why, as I'm modeling this API on another project I've done. Should I not be sending both get and post requests to the /api/posts?

Comment: Can you add how you're making the request?

Comment: @molamk In Postman? I'm sending a POST request to localhost:3000/api/posts with body fields of title: test and location: thailand

Comment: So that's the problem. You're __sending on port 3000__, but __listening on port 5000__

Comment: @molamk Ah ok. I thought I needed to have my React server and Express server running on different ports or I would get errors.

Comment: check out my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our exchange in the comment, here's the problem

- The request is **sent to port 3000**
- The Node.js server is **listening on port 5000**.

To solve that you just need to format your request to `http://localhost:5000/api/posts`

## Notes

- You still need to **run `React` and `Node.js` on different ports**
- You only need to **change the port for your HTTP request**

Comment: if this was true the error "Cannot POST /api/posts" would not appear.

Comment: How is that? React runs by default on port 3000, which does not support POST requests on a `/api/posts` route. The message is valid

Comment: hm, I think if he got this error it means that he could connect to the server, but the route was not found on server. If there was a connection error like this, the request would just time out without receiving any response.

Comment: This is just factually wrong. React catches the request and returns `Cannot POST /api/posts`. You can __try it yourself__, [here's a link where you can try that]

Comment: @molamk So to ensure I'm understanding, in my form, I would change the action to "/api/posts:5000"? Would this also work in a production environment?

Comment: @Mknerr Yes `/api/posts:5000`. It will also work in production if your server will be listening on port `5000`

Comment: @molamk I checked that my server and mongodb are running and I sent a POST request via Postman to localhost:3000/api/posts:5000 but got the error <pre>Cannot POST /api/posts:5000</pre>

Comment: Not `localhost:3000/api/posts:5000`. Use __`localhost:5000/api/posts`__. I'll edit my answer too. @Mknerr

Comment: @molamk Apologies if I'm being dense, but in my form's action, if I send to "/api/posts:5000" I get the same error, but I don't think I'd want to send action="localhost:5000/api/posts" since that wouldn't be production-friendly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188735/discussion-between-molamk-and-mknerr).

Answer (score 1):

At the end of Post Route you have to export it.

```
module.exports = router;
```

this makes you be able to import it in app.js like you did.

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes with same endpoint.

```
//Router
app.use('/api/photos', photos);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);
app.use('/api/posts', recs);
```

I think you wanted a different endpoint for the third route.

```
//Router
app.use('/api/photos', photos);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);
app.use('/api/recs', recs);
```

Comment: True. But that does not solve the problem, since in the original case the first router on `/api/posts` is called

Comment: Thanks for catching that! It's still throwing the same error when I post though.

Answer (score 0):

The action route on the form does not match the post route on the server side.

```
<form action="/api/posts" method="post" className="form-container">

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
```

The action route should match the post route for the post action to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and it took me almost half an hour to debug and find the solution.

- The error:

[image: The error]

- In my case, on the server side, I had used "get" request to declare createPosts instead of "post" request.
  [image: server side]
- I just changed the "get" request on createPosts to "post", and everything worked fine. I was able to post on the frontend and get a the data.
  [image]

[image]